# while implementing a concept in javascript i have been facing some odd behaviour from addEventListener function i created to get scrollY value

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, animation

javascript

```
let temp
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
  temp=document.createElement('div')
  temp.id=`sq${i}`
  temp.classList.add('square')
  temp.classList.add('new')
  temp.style.top=(100+(i*5)).toString()+"px"
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo-wrapper")[0].appendChild(temp)
}
window.addEventListener('scroll',(event)=>{
  let scroll =this.scrollY;
  console.log(scroll)
  let div
  let rate
  for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
    div = document.getElementById(`sq${j}`)
    let {
      top: t,
    } = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    rate=(400-modulus(scroll-t))/4
    rate*=2
    rate-=(rate)/4
    if(modulus(scroll-t)<=400 && (rate)>20){
      div.style.height = (rate).toString()+"px";
      }
    else{
      div.style.height = "20px";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>hey man this is my page</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="demo-wrapper ">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.square{
  position: relative;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#DC3F0A ;
}
/* .extender{
  
} */
body{
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #353433;
}
html{
  height:200%;
}
.new:hover{
  background-color:white;
}
```

problem:
when i run it and scroll down the scroll value fluctuates and the the scroll bar glitches can someone help me here

i don't know what to ask you just have to run the code and see for yourself coz i can't explain the problem and for some reason they want me to give more descriptive idea of the problem but that i don't have

Comment: Please put your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When I run this it appears to be working fine. You are getting console.logs of the scrollY for every so often from 0-100 for each scroll because your callback in the eventlistener is updating the state of the boxes. The scrollbar is a bit glitchy which I think is a performance issue.

You could update your code by using requestAnimationFrame and pass your callback to requestAnimationFrame inside your eventlistener. It would look something like this.

```
function updateSquares() {
  let div;
  let rate;
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    div = document.getElementById(`sq${j}`);
    let { top: t } = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    rate = (400 - modulus(scroll - t)) / 4;
    rate *= 2;
    rate -= rate / 4;
    if (modulus(scroll - t) <= 400 && rate > 20) {
      div.style.height = `${rate}px`;
    } else {
      div.style.height = '20px';
    }
  }
}

let scroll = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  scroll = window.scrollY;
  requestAnimationFrame(updateSquares);
});
```